# What is the most efficient way to calculate a future date in SQL based on a number of working days without loops?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date

Calculate a number of working days in SQL and return the date without using Loops.

I need to create a function in Microsoft SQL server management studio that will take in a date and a number of working days as a variable and then return an end date that is however many working days in the future.

I have achieved this using a loop but was wondering if there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

The function is as follows:

```
[dbo].[AddWorkingDays]
(
@originaldate date,
@daystoadd INT
)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
Declare @days INT;
Declare @counter INT;
Declare @duedate date;

SET @days = 1
SET @counter = 0 


WHILE (@counter < @daystoadd)
        BEGIN
            set @duedate = dateadd(DAY,@days,@originaldate)
                IF @duedate Not in (SELECT [date-off] from [Non-working-days-table])
            BEGIN    
                SET @counter = @counter + 1  
            END
            BEGIN
                SET @days = @days +1
            END
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @duedate

END
```

Comment: Yes, don't use a loop, use set-based logic. for this it's often very useful to have a *calendar table* handy -  eg in a shared utility database. you can then select from a calendar table using aggregations to compute the minimun future date that's greater than a sum of valid working days etc

Comment: if you know the day of the week for your start date, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate the enddate with some clever math

Comment: You can do that sure if you're just dealing with normal Monday-Friday "working" days but anything else such as custom business working days, perhaps Saturday is, or regional bank-holidays make it more awkward, a calendar is usually the most reliable option.

Comment: @Stu, agree, i kinda assumed OP wasn't interested in that cause his logic doesn't handle that now, but yes, that, together with stuff like easter etc, it gets much more complicated

Comment: @stu I do have a calendar table (non-working-days) which I am using in my function. This table contains a list of all weekends and any other holidays that are not considered working days. I am just unsure how best to go about doing this without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the approach to the task.See this example:

nwd - non-working-day.
Original date(startdt) not included in count. It doesn't matter)

```
-- test data
create table nwd (date_off date);
insert into nwd values
('2023-06-03'),('2023-06-04'),('2023-06-10'),('2023-06-11'),('2023-06-14')
,('2023-06-17'),('2023-06-18'),('2023-06-19')
;

declare @startdt date;
set @startdt=cast('2023-05-30' as date);
declare @daystoadd int;
set @daystoadd=13;

-- query
with t1 as(
select @startdt startdt,date_off
  ,datediff(d,@startdt,date_off) dif
  ,row_number()over(order by date_off) nwdCnt
  ,datediff(d,@startdt,date_off) -row_number()over(order by date_off) workdays
from nwd
where date_off>@startdt
)
select max(date_off) maxdoff,max(workdays) mwd
  ,case when max(workdays) is not null then
         dateadd(d,@daystoadd-max(workdays),max(date_off)) 
   else dateadd(d,@daystoadd,@startdt)
   end targetdt
from t1
where workdays<@daystoadd;
```

CTE result

| startdt | date_off | dif | nwdCnt | workdays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-03 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-04 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-10 | 11 | 3 | 8 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-11 | 12 | 4 | 8 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-14 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-17 | 18 | 6 | 12 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-18 | 19 | 7 | 12 |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-19 | 20 | 8 | 12 |

Target query result (draft) with startdt=2023-05-30 and daystoadd=13

| startdt | maxdoff | mwd | targetdt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-30 | 2023-06-19 | 12 | 2023-06-20 |

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/at-ddbYM)

Upd1. Corrected to take into account the comment of user1191247 for dates before first non-working-day in nwd table.